# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null. The functionality was working recently but suddenly this error appears

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose, search

I am using this same search functionality on the production server and it is working there fine. Suddenly this error appears as I used it on a development server. Also, I observed that the backend code showing status code 200 when I searched a query in the search box and submit it. The below-shown code is the code that I wrote on the frontend and backend. What can be the problem

**backend code:**

```
exports.listSearch =async (req, res) => {
    try {
         const { search } = req.query;
    if (search) {
      await Job.find(
            {
                $or: [{ title: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' } ,body: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' },location: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' }}]
            },
            (err, jobs) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(400).json({
                        error: errorHandler(err)
                    });
                }
                res.json(jobs);
            }
        ).select('-photo -body').sort({updatedAt:-1});
    }
    } catch (err) {
       console.error(err.message);
       res.status(500).send('Server error');
```

**Front end code:**

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import React,{ useState } from 'react';
import { listSearchPvt } from '../../actions/privateJob';

const SearchPvt = () => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        search: undefined,
        results: [],
        searched: false,
        message: '',
    });

    const { search, results, searched, message, } = values;

    const searchSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        listSearchPvt({ search }).then(data => {
            setValues({ ...values, results: data, searched: true, message: `${data.length} jobs found` });
        });
    };
 
    const handleChange = e => {
        
        setValues({ ...values, search: e.target.value, searched: false, results: [] });
    };

    const searchedJobs = (results = []) => {
        return (
            <div className="bg-light">
                {message && <p className="extra-small text-light-gray " >{message}</p>}

                {results.map((privateJob, i) => {
                    return (
                        
                        <div key={i} >
                        <Link href={`/privateJobs/${privateJob.slug}`}>
                       <a>
                        <h3  className="text-dark " style={{fontFamily:`'Source Serif Pro' ,serif` ,lineHeight:'1.9rem'}}>
                        <span> </span>{privateJob.title}
                        </h3>
                        <div className="line"></div>
                       </a>
                        </Link>
                      
                    </div>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        );
    };

    const searchForm = () => (

        <form onSubmit={searchSubmit} style={{width: '100%', display: 'flex' ,alignItems:'end' ,height: '2.4rem',justifyContent:'space-between',alignContent:'center',alignItems:'center' }} className="btn nbtn btn-success" >
           <input className='btn nbtn btn-success' style={{width:'100%'}} type="search" placeholder="Search Jobs" onChange={handleChange} />
          <button className="btn nbtn btn-dark lead my-1"   type="submit" >Search</button>
         </form>
    );

    return (
        <>
       <div style={{display:'block'}}>  
        <div className="my-3">{searchForm()}</div>
       
        {searched && <div className='blog m-2 ' >{searchedJobs(results)}</div>}
       
        </div>
       
        </>
    );
}
export default SearchPvt;
```

Comment: `data` might be null. Add a null check before setting the response value to the state,

Comment: What is `listSearchPvt` returning as a resolved value for the Promise chain?

Comment: export const listSearchPvt =async (params) => {
    console.log('search params', params);
    let query = queryString.stringify(params);
    console.log('query params', query);
    return await fetch(`${API}/privateJobs/search?${query}`, {
        method: 'GET'
    })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
};

Comment: this is the listSearchPvt function which is fetching data from the backend. Morgan is giving 304 status when query is searched in search bar